# Converting string to type 'Date'

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have used the Calendar class to get the current Date. Now I want to convert that date to Date format so that it can be stored in database with format "yyyy-mm-dd". I tried to convert it with using SimpleDate format but I got error. The code is as follows. Help. Thanks in advance.

```
class dateDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


    String stringdate ;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    String year,month,day;  

    Calendar currentDate;
    Date validity;

    currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    year = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.YEAR );
    month = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.MONTH );
    day = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );


    stringdate = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;


    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    try
    {
    validity = sdf.parse ( stringdate );
    }

     catch(Exception e)
    {
            System.out.println(""+e);
    }

    System.out.println("Current Date is:"+stringdate);


    System.out.println("Date is"+validity);             

    }
}
```

Comment: If you plan to insert it into a relational database with JDBC, you shouldn't transform it to a String, but to a java.sql.Date.

Comment: Can you please update what error is thrown..??

Comment: Change `Date validity;` into `Date validity = null;` if you got `The local variable validity may not have been initialized`.

Comment: change `stringdate = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;` into `stringdate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;`

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and got `java.text.ParseException`. Just to remove the error, you can simply change the "/" to "-" in your program BUT it won't give you the correct date.

Try this revised solution, in String, java.util.Date and java.sql.Date formats:

```
class dateDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        String validity = "";
        Date validityDate = null;
        java.sql.Date validateDateSql = null;

        Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            validity = sdf.format(currentDate);
            validityDate = sdf.parse(validity);
            validateDateSql = new java.sql.Date(validityDate.getTime());                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Take note of the SimpleDateFormat setting: `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `yyyy-mm-dd`. It matters.

Comment: Thanks! Would appreciate if you could "Accept" the answer by pressing the check button.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answer of Roxinus for the correct code.

I recommand you to always look at the documentation of Java API when you write code. It is extremely usefull and you find often how to use the code :
[Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Database connectors can handle dates, don't convert it to String, it's not a good practice.

You could rewrite the code like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MyTable values(?)");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime()); 
pstmt.setDate(1, sqlDate)
```